# Repushing of gem not allowed, but gem not found when trying to yank

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I am currently trying to publish a gem to rubygems.org and having some difficulty. I have built the gem on my system, but when I go to push it to rubygems, I am receiving this error:

```
// ♥ gem push upcoming-0.2.0.gem
Pushing gem to https://rubygems.org...
Repushing of gem versions is not allowed.
Please use `gem yank` to remove bad gem releases.
```

When I go to yank the version, I receive this:

```
// ♥ gem yank upcoming-0.2.0.gem -v 0.2.0
Yanking gem from https://rubygems.org...
This gem could not be found
```

Here is the terminal output for the gem build:

```
// ♥ gem build upcoming.gemspec
WARNING:  open-ended dependency on nokogiri (>= 0) is not recommended
  if nokogiri is semantically versioned, use:
    add_runtime_dependency 'nokogiri', '~> 0'
WARNING:  open-ended dependency on pry (>= 0, development) is not recommended
  if pry is semantically versioned, use:
    add_development_dependency 'pry', '~> 0'
WARNING:  See http://guides.rubygems.org/specification-reference/ for help
  Successfully built RubyGem
  Name: upcoming
  Version: 0.2.0
  File: upcoming-0.2.0.gem
```

Does anyone know where I am going wrong here or how to bypass this issue to publish the gem?

update: I think the issue is that the gem's name is already taken on rubygems.

```
// ♥ gem yank upcoming -v 0.2.0
Yanking gem from https://rubygems.org...
You do not have permission to delete this gem.
```

Anyone know the quickest way to rename the gem? All of my files and their contents contain the word upcoming, which was the original name for it. Is there an easy way to rename it without renaming all of those files and changing their contents? I tried renaming the gemspec file to upcoming-denver-concerts.gemspec and got this error:

```
// ♥ gem build upcoming-denver-concerts.gemspec
WARNING:  See http://guides.rubygems.org/specification-reference/ for help
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::InvalidSpecificationException)
    ["upcoming.gemspec"] are not files
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first message (`This gem could not be found`) happens when you've already pushed the current version of your gem (0.2.0) to Rubygems. You can't push it twice.

The second message, I think, is from misusing the Rubygems CLI. The helpfile states `Usage: gem yank GEM -v VERSION`. I think if you changed your command to the following:

```
$ gem yank upcoming -v 0.2.0
```

Your `yank` would succeed.

The messages in your build are just warnings-- worth fixing but not preventing a successful build.

Comment: i think the takeaway here is that yanking a version of a gem doesn't allow it to get pushed again right?

Comment: I'm not sure about that. The messages in the original post could be produced without ever successfully yanking the gem.

Comment: Thanks for taking a look guys! I added an edit to the question. Maybe you guys have some insight into the question in the edit?

Comment: I don't know a way to rename a gem you're working on, other than changing the code and directory names. `upcoming` should only be autogenerated in your code about 15 times, so a find-and-replace should handle that nicely. As to the new error you posted, a file is trying to load `upcoming.gemspec` (the old name)-- that's the next file you need to change.

Comment: If you do go the manual-rename route, this documentation should help sort out the right usage: http://guides.rubygems.org/name-your-gem/

Answer (score 0):

I was able to rename the gemspec file, `git add .` and gem push (new gemspec filename) and the gem successfully registered. Thanks all!